# Displaying text value when there is a certain value in another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list

Say I have three Columns:

1. Likelihood (1-5)
2. Consequence (1-5)
3. Risk Score (1-25)

The risk score is calculated based on multiplication of Likelihood and Consequence.I would also like a column that interprets the range of score in the Risk Score Column and provides one of the following four: Low, Medium, High Extreme.

Here is what I came with but can't seem to get it to work.

=IF(or([Risk Score]<="6","Low"), IF[Risk Score] >"6" or <="12","Medium"), IF[Risk Score] >"12" or <="19","High"), IF[Risk Score] >"19","Extreme")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(I am putting this here as I am new and do not have enough Rep to add a comment)

You have a few errors in the Syntax of your formula. Parenthesis in the incorrect places and OR functions in the wrong place as well as incorrect use of OR in the IF Statements.

The OR Function should come after the IF Function for those that require an OR comparison and each OR Value is separated by a comma.

Check out the [following link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)) which gives some good examples of how to structure the statements. As an example from the site:

*=IF(OR([Column1]>[Column2], [Column1]<[Column3]), "OK", "Not OK")
If 15 is greater than 9 or less than 8, return "OK". (OK)*

Also as it can be easier to run through a working sample against an example I have provided the formula I was able to achieve your desired result with:

```
=IF([Risk Score]<=6,"Low",IF(OR([Risk Score]>6,[Risk Score]<=12),"Medium",IF(OR([Risk Score]>12,[Risk Score]<=19),"High",IF([Risk Score]>19,"Extreme"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample formula for your reference:

```
=IF([Risk Score]="","",
    IF([Risk Score]<=6,"Low",
        IF([Risk Score]<=12,"Medium",
            IF([Risk Score]<=19,"High","Extreme")
        )
    )
)
```

And the outcome:

[image]